# How to display the content of a file in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular9

I have an Angular App, and the user uploads two files there, json and xml. What I want to do is show the contents of the file. I have tried one approach, processing the file line by line and adding it to a string and then show the string. But that way I lose the indentation and other things too. Is there any way I can show the uploaded file directly without having to go all the trouble. And I have one more thing to do, I have a list of line number and I want to maybe add custom color to that line numbers.
e.g `[2,3,4]` is the list of line number , and so in the uploaded file, I would like to color line numbers 2,3,4 as red. How can I do all this ?

Answer (score 0):

The iFrame tag is often a good way to simply display files, but I don't have experiences in using the iFrame tag with JSON or XML files and it would not directly solve your problem of modifying them...